# Casting std::wstring to const wchar_t x[]

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void get_id(int i, std::vector<item>& _items) {

    auto cpool = get_db_connection_pool();
    auto con = cpool->get_connection();
    db::result m;

    int _id;

    if (i == 1) {               

        const wchar_t sql[] = LR"***(
            SELECT * FROM TABLE1                    
        )***";

        db::statement st(con, sql);

        m = st.execute().into(_id);

        while (m.move_next()) {                 
            _items.push_back(item {_id});
        }
    }
    else {
        const wchar_t sql[] = LR"***(
            SELECT * FROM TABLE2                    
        )***";

        db::statement st(con, sql);

        m = st.execute().into(_id);

        while (m.move_next()) {                 
            _items.push_back(item {_id});
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the code

```
        db::statement st(con, sql);

        m = st.execute().into(_id);

        while (m.move_next()) {                 
            _items.push_back(item {_id});
        }
```

is written duplicated in the if-else statement.  I would like to move that part outside of the if else case like this:

```
void get_id(int i, std::vector<item>& _items) {

    auto cpool = get_db_connection_pool();
    auto con = cpool->get_connection();
    db::result m;

    int _id;

    if (i == 1) {               

        const wchar_t sql[] = LR"***(
            SELECT * FROM TABLE1                    
        )***";
    }
    else {
        const wchar_t sql[] = LR"***(
            SELECT * FROM TABLE2                    
        )***";
    }


    db::statement st(con, sql);

    m = st.execute().into(_id);

    while (m.move_next()) {                 
        _items.push_back(item {_id});
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing `sql[]` in the if-else case with a temporary `std::wstring` but I can't figure out how to cast `std::wstring` to `const wchar_t sql[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::wstring` has a member function `c_str` that will return a `const wchar_t*` to the underlying string.  As long as `db::statement` takes a `const wchar_t []` or `const wchar_t *` then you can use

```
std::wstring sql;
if (i == 1) {               

    sql = LR"***(
        SELECT * FROM TABLE1                    
    )***";
}
else {
    sql = LR"***(
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2                    
    )***";
}

db::statement st(con, sql.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks, I know of c_str() but didnt think of doing it like that. Thanks! Do you know a site where I can read about c++ types? I'm new in the c++ game my knowledge is mostly in c#

Comment: @PresidentCamacho I use [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) quite a bit.  You may also want to get a nice [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)